# Out of memory problem on constructing large list in Mathematica running on Linux

Tags: memory

I have Mathematica running on Mac as well as Linux, my Mac as 16GB of RAM with core i5 processor (2-core) and Linux has 24GB of RAM on i7 (4-core). The problem is that the following command:

```
T=Range[10^11]
```

executes on Mac but on Linux it generates:

```
General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure,{Range[100000000000]}]
```

Any idea as to what could be causing this issue on a machine with better configuration?

Comment: Seems odd that this would execute on your Mac, since `10^11*4 bytes = 400GB`. Perhaps it wrote to disk? How much free memory do you have on disk? What's the result of running `ByteCount[T]`?

Comment: Now that you have mentioned it, even on Mac the kernel quits. I think it never worked to begin with. I will close this question.\